# how many sequences above 1,2,3,4,5,6,7 that don't contain odd couples

Tags: combinatorics, recurrence-relations, recursion

I got stucked a little with this question. would appreciate your help.
the question is "find a recursive relation that counts how many sequences of order n above ${1,2,3,4,5,6,7}$ that don't contain odd couples of numbers (for example it can't contain 11 or 13 or 15 or 17 or 31 or 33 etc...)"

so what I did is the following:

- for a sequence beginning with 2 or 4 or 6 there's no limit so another $a_{n-1}$ options
- for a sequence beginning with 1 it can't get 1 or 3 or 5 or 7 afterwards. so let's look at the total number of legal options $a_{n-1}$ and subtract the legal sequences beginning with 1 or 3 or 5 or 7 = $4*a_{n-2}$. so in total we get $a_{n-1}-4*a_{n-2}$ options in total.
- the same goes for a sequence beginning with 3 or 5 or 7 as for a sequence beginning with 1 described above.

thus, if we sum all mentioned we get $a_n=7a_{n-1}-16a_{n-2}$. but I found that the correct answer would be $a_n=3a_{n-1}+12a_{n-2}$ from some reason. what am I doing wrong? would appreciate your advice,

Comment: It seems that you think there are $4a_{n-2}$ sequences of length $n-1$ that begin with an odd number. But that cannot be true because some of the $a_{n-2}$ sequences will _themselves_ start with an odd number.

Comment: @HenningMakholm maybe I don't understand something. but what I did is - from all the $a_{n-1}$ possible sequences I subtract those beginning with an odd number. thus the possible sequences shouldn't begin with an odd digit. what do I miss?

Comment: You're counting "those beginning with an odd number" incorrectly. For example, one of the $a_{n-2}$ sequences would be $7,2,2,1$, and when you multiply $a_{n-2}$ by $4$ you get things like $5,7,2,2,1$ which was never included in your $a_n$ in your first place, so things go wrong when you try to subtract them.

Comment: @HenningMakholm I can't understand why multiplying $a_{n-2}$ by $4$ causes that such a sequence appear $5,7,2,2,1$?

Comment: Well, what are you multiplying $a_{n-2}$ by $4$ for in the first place? I thought you were imagining taking _each legal sequence_ of length $n-2$ (because that's what there are $a_{n-2}$ of), and putting each of the odd elements in front of it. If that is not your reasoning for $4a_{n-2}$, please explain what it is.

Comment: More concretely, let's consider the $n=3$ case. Obviously we have $a_1=7$ and $a_2=33$. Now you ask how many of the length-3 sequences that with $1$ -- you say that will be $a_2-4a_1 = 33-4\cdot 7=5$. But there are much more than 5 -- e.g. there are 7 sequences starting with `1,2` alone. Try writing down the $4\cdot 7=28$ sequences you're subtracting; you will find there are not that many.

Comment: @HenningMakholm for example, let's assume $a_n$ begins with $1$. then it can get each digit of 1-7. from the terms of question, the valid possibilities would be only 2 or 4 or 6. So what I think I did is - I take all the possible options that can appear after this $1$ and the possible options are $a_{n-1}$ and then I subtract the bad possibilities - meaning sequences of size $n-2$ beginning with 1 or 3 or 5 or 7. that's because I don't want to get the sequence 1,1,X,X,X,... or 1,3,X,X,... or 1,5,X,X,... or 1,7,X,X,... so here there are 4 bad options - that's why $4a_{n-2}$

Comment: and those "bad options" are by themselves valid sequences of size $n-2$. I can't really get what's wrong with what I do..

Comment: x @Ami: No, that does _not_ give $4a_{n-2}$ -- because when you said, for example "1,7,X,X" and want to instantiate "X,X" with _all_ of the valid examples of size $n-2$, then you also get, for example $X,X=3,2$, and then you're suddenly excluding $1,7,3,2$. But that _was not counted in the first place_, because the $7,3,2$ is invalid and therefore is not included in the $7a_{n-1}$ you started out with.

Comment: @HenningMakholm I'm very confused. can you recommend maybe a good literature where I can read about methods of solving such problems? thanks again for your time!

Comment: x @Ami: To un-confuse yourself, I repeat my suggestion of trying to write down all the valid 2-element sequences start with an odd number. According to your way of counting there should be $4\cdot a_1 = 4\cdot 7=28$. You will find that there are not that many. **Please grab a piece of paper and do this.** Then try to figure out which sequences you were imaging there ought to be when you thought there should be 28 and which of those are not there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $E_n$ denote the number of good sequences that end in an even number, $O_n$ the number that end in an odd number, and $a_n$ the total (so $a_n$ is the answer you seek).

We can always append an even number so $$E_{n}=3\times a_{n-1}$$  We can only append an odd number to a sequence that ends in an even number, so $$O_{n}=4\times E_{n-1}=12\times a_{n-2}$$  Thus $$a_n=E_n+O_n=3a_{n-1}+12a_{n-2}$$

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you think there are $4a_{n-2}$ sequences of length $n-1$ that begin with an odd number. But that cannot be true because some of the $a_{n-2}$ sequences will *themselves* start with an odd number.

What I would do here would be to set up *two* sequences, with $b_n$ being the number of sequences of length $n$ that begin with an even number and $c_n$ counting sequences that begin with an odd number. Then we have
$$ \begin{align} b_n &= 3(b_{n-1}+c_{n-1}) \\ c_n &= 4b_{n-1} \end{align} $$
And introducing $a_n=b_n+c_n$ this becomes
$$ \begin{align} b_n &= 3a_{n-1} \\ a_n &= 4b_{n-1} + 3a_{n-1} \end{align} $$
Substitute in the expression for $b_n$ to get
$$ a_n = 12a_{n-2} + 3a_{n-1} $$
I don't know why your "correct" answer has a different sign for the $12a_{n-2}$ term.